# Regular expression for alphanumeric and some special characters

Tags: c#, regex

Can someone please tell me how I can write a regular expression that contains on alphanumeric and special character `( ) / -`? Here are some examples it should match.

```
a1-2/)(2w-z1)
1)/-1aqw
(q1/(-
1234qwx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex with all the permitted characters and rangers specified in a `character class`:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9()/-]+$
```

[**Recommended RegEx Reference**](http://regular-expressions.info)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want *at least one* alphanumerical character and *at least one* special character, use

```
([A-Za-z0-9][()/-]|[()/-][A-Za-z0-9])
```

Since we want to have both an alphanumerical character and a special character in our string, there *must* be a spot where we have one next to another, so we look for that spot — either an alphanumerical character followed by a special character, or a special character followed by an alphanumerical character.